# google map infoWindows

Tags: jquery, google-maps

I have a concern, I will wish that when I click on a hyperlink it focuses on me and shows me this InfoWindow. Unfortunately it's been two days that I try without success.

```
<script>
var villes = [
                {/literal}{data_gmap}{literal}
            ];
        function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 12,
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(47.90414530044006, 1.9050121307373047),
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                scrollwheel: true
        }
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions);
                setMarkers(map, villes);
        }
function centerPoi(longitude, latitude){
var mapOptions = {
zoom:17,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(longitude, latitude),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        scrollwheel: true
}
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions);
        setMarkers(map, villes);
}
function setMarkers(map, locations) {
var image = 'uploads/images/logomaps.png';
        for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
var villes = locations[i];
        var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(villes[1], villes[2]);
        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatLng,
                map: map,
                animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                icon: image
        });
        (function (i) {
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
        var villes = locations[i];
        infoWindow.close();
        infoWindow.setContent(
        "<div id='boxcontent' style='font-family:Calibri'><strong >"+ villes[0] +" €</strong><br /><span style='font-size:12px;color:#333'>"+ villes[3] +"<br/>"+ villes[4] +"<br/>"+ villes [5] + "</span></div>");
        infoWindow.open(map, this);
        });
        })(i);

}
}
</script>
```

And my hyperlink:

```
 <a href="#" onClick="centerPoi(\''.$data[$i]['latitude'].'\',\''.$data[$i]['longitude'].'\'); google.maps.event.addListener(marker'.$i.', \'click\');" class="hyperlink'.$i.'">'.$data[$i]['nom'].'</a>
```

If someone has an idea or can guide me?

Thanks !

Comment: Are you getting any errors on the JavaScript console?

Comment: No errors ! Because when I click on marker it works well but not on the hyperlink

Comment: Your markers have already `click` event listeners attached in `setMarkers()` function. And you are trying to create your map over and over again on each click on link. You should dive in more on docs of google to understand usage better. Removing listener from `<a>` `onClick` may work by the way.

Comment: @user3414416 I can't help better than Google, they have very well explained documents and examples which you can easily understand. But you need to also try examples yourself to understand better.